# Does PHP with Neo4j work with a selene server

Tags: php, neo4j, configuration, server, webserver

I am trying to configure PHP with my neo4j graph data. 
This is what I've tried:

```
<?php
// Connection to the database
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create ()->addConnection ( 'bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:neo4jj@127.0.0.1:7687' )
//-> addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:neo4jj@127.0.0.1:7687')
->build ();

if ($client != null) {
    echo ($client . $_REQUEST);

    $query = "MATCH (n:RECORD) RETURN n.recordID";
    $result = $client->run ( $query );
} elseif ($client == null) {

    echo ("Sorry. Connection failed...");
}

// foreach ($result->getRecords() as $record) {
// echo sprintf('ID number is : %s', $record->value('recordID'));

?>
```

I am trying to run this on a Selene server. Is there something wrong with the code or is the Selene server the wrong server to do this? Please let me know what the solution to this problem is.

You can see the error I am receiving here: https://selene.hud.ac.uk/irr/configNeo4j.php

Comment: Can you specify what issue you are encountering ?

Comment: I have just added a link to my question

Comment: Strange, that seems to be an empty page ? Are you getting any actual errors ?

Comment: I don't actually think the error is caused by the code but it might be something to do with the selene server

Comment: another problem I'm considering is the library that is being used

Comment: Selene is not actually a software is it ? It seems to be the DNS name of the server ... which seems to be running a vanilla Apache webserver ? If you've installed the library correctly it should work then ...

Comment: I have imported the library from github. Shouldn't that work?